# Bonobo git server: How to do an incremental backup of all repos

Tags: backup, git

We have Bonobo git server running on Windows server and have to copy all repos to another Windows server, so we can restore Bonobo git server even after our office has been burnt to the ground. We have SMB and SFTP at our hands for now.

The connection between the two servers is slow and the repos are blown up, so for a nightly backup we would need incremental backup.

Can we just use command line's `copy` command to copy over the changed files from the Repositories subfolder from one server to another, or should we opt for rsync? Does (S)FTP support copying changed files only?

Is there anything we have to look at regarding metadata, that is not stored in the Repositories subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see is using a backup/restore tool that can manage well incremental backups, and replicate at least the app_data folder. This will create a stand-by secondary site (not an app replica) you can use if primary is dead.
There are many services can provide this. I use backup@huge that can backup the app folder, or also perform a DR of entire server. You can have this sleeping, or perform an incremental restore every day to you secondary server.